# Cumulative sum on different columns grouped by date and filtered differently

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to create three cumulative sum columns based on three different column. Each cumulative sum must be calculated as follows:

- should be grouped by the same date in the `dte` column
- column A should be filtered ASC before cumulative sum operation is done
- column B & C should be filtered DESC before cumulative sum operation.

Should I create new tables with columns A, B, C separated from each other?

```
+-----------+----+----------+---+----+-----+----------+----------+----------+
|    dte    | id | last_dte | a | b  |  c  | a_cumsum | b_cumsum | c_cumsum |
+-----------+----+----------+---+----+-----+----------+----------+----------+
| 12/4/2018 |  1 | 3-Dec    | 2 |  8 | 200 |        2 |          |          |
| 12/4/2018 |  2 | 3-Dec    | 2 |  5 | 150 |        4 |          |          |
| 12/4/2018 |  8 | 3-Dec    | 2 | 25 |  88 |        6 |          |          |
| 12/4/2018 |  9 | 3-Dec    | 2 | 89 | 456 |        8 |          |          |
| 12/3/2018 | 12 | 2-Dec    | 2 |  1 | 124 |        2 |          |          |
| 12/3/2018 | 13 | 2-Dec    | 2 |  5 |  46 |        4 |          |          |
| 12/3/2018 | 19 | 2-Dec    | 2 | 22 |  10 |        6 |          |          |
+-----------+----+----------+---+----+-----+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic example of a [Cumulative Sum DAX Pattern](https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/).

You do not need separate tables.

As a calculated column

```
a_cum = 
VAR CurrentID = [id]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table01[a] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( Table01, Table01[dte] ),
            Table01[id] <= CurrentID
        )
    )
```

The `b_cum` and `c_cum` columns are analogous. Just switch out the column you're referencing and change the direction of the inequality for DESC instead of ASC.
For example,

```
b_cum = 
VAR CurrentID = [id]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table01[b] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( Table01, Table01[dte] ),
            Table01[id] >= CurrentID
        )
    )
```

---

This should give you a table like this:

[image: Calculated Columns]

---

Note that these are ordering the cumulative sum by the `id` column (ASC for `a_cum` and descending for `b_cum` and `c_cum`). If you need to sort by the values of the columns rather than their `id`, then I'd suggest adding a calculated column for each to rank them how you want. Then use the `rank` column instead of the `id` column in your DAX.

Comment: This gives me the same result for each day.

Comment: yes  I need to order by the value column , not sure how to apply this