# How to count cumulatively count occurrences in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
column1   Column2
A         01/01/2020
B         01/01/2020
C         04/01/2020
A         07/01/2020
B         07/01/2020
A         12/01/2020
C         10/01/2020
```

What I am trying to do is count how many times a value in column1 has occurred. So I want to be able to end up with this:

```
column1   Column2      column3
A         01/01/2020   1
B         01/01/2020   1
C         04/01/2020   1
A         07/01/2020   2
B         07/01/2020   2
A         12/01/2020   3
C         10/01/2020   2
```

I found DAX to count how many times in total a value occurs but I can't seem to find how to count them cumulatively.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is the same as with a [cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578751), just with `COUNT` instead:

```
column3 =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Table1[column1] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[column1] ),
    Table1[Column2] <= EARLIER ( Table1[Column2] )
)
```

See also:
[Cumulative Total DAX Pattern](https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/)

[Cumulative sum on different columns grouped by date and filtered differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621328/cumulative-sum-on-different-columns-grouped-by-date-and-filtered-differently)